# Making matrix look sharper

Tags: matrices

How can I make this matrix look sharper or fancier? There must be a package to make it look better. Right now it looks like an old 80s TeX table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
    \centering

        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & Relevant  & Irrelevant  &  Total    \\ \hline
            Recommended    & VP& FP& VP +FP         \\ \hline
            Not recommended & FN     & VN & FN +VN\\ \hline
            Total             & VP + FN   &   FP + VN            & $N$ \\ \hline

        \end{tabular}




\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Read the documentation of `booktabs` it contains some pretty good advices on pretty tables in general besides the documentation of its own macros.

Comment: I personally prefer to have a table only if necessary. The information content of this particular table isn't tremendous. The total VP and FN is VP+FN. True, but I'd assume that this goes without saying. Is there any way to suppress the table or to really focus on the relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose one of these two layouts, with some colour and a single thick vertical rule :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}
        \begin{tabular}{r!{\color{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\vrule width 0.25em}ccc}
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{}& Relevant & Irrelevant & Total \\ \cmidrule[1pt]{2-4}
            Recommended & VP& FP& VP +FP \\[1ex]
            Not recommended & FN & VN & FN +VN\\[1ex]
            Total & VP + FN & FP + VN & $N$ \\ \cmidrule[1pt]{2-4}
        \end{tabular}

\vskip 1cm
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{r!{\color{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\vrule width 0.25em\enspace }ccc}
        \rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor{white}}& Relevant & Irrelevant & Total \\
            Recommended & VP& FP& VP +FP \\[0.5ex]
            Not recommended & FN & VN & FN +VN\\[0.5ex]
            Total & VP + FN & FP + VN & $N$ \\ \cmidrule[1pt]{2-4}
        \end{tabular}%(l{0.2em})
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Many people recommand `booktabs`. Simple and elegant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
& Relevant    & Irrelevant        &  Total \\  
\midrule
Recommended   & VP      & FP      & VP +FP \\ 
Not commended & FN      & VN      & FN +VN \\ 
Total         & VP + FN & FP + VN & $N$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the previous code]